# I have a horizontal scroll on my web page that I can't get rid of

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've built a page using Bootstrap 4 and my footer has a 20px gap to the right hand side. There is a horizontal scroll on the page as well, which I thought was the footer so I deleted and it made no difference. I've been working on this late at night so it's entirely possible I've missed something but I can't see what!

I've looked at the container, the body, tried deleting sections to the point where I deleted everything and the horizontal scroll was still there.

I've uploaded the site here so if you want to check the code and CSS using developer tools you can:
http://mharrisondesign.co.uk/sites/sublime_new/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The div right after the `<!--Navigate ENDS-->` comment has some `margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;` style. Removing the `margin-right` seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Yes I tried this but it affected the whole page and threw other elements out. I've figured out the issue and it was how I'd nested a container within another as well as some custom CSS that I'd created that was overriding other bootstrap elements. Using container-fluid in a slightly different format sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `row` under a `container` div. Otherwise it will create a horizontal scroll.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     -------
   </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     -------
   </div>
</div>
```

Easy Solution but bad:
Use `overflow-x: hidden;` on `body` tag.